# What are the instructions to read the numbers from the user keyboard using a loop? Are 'labels' required?

Tags: assembly, mips32

I have to write a MIPS assembly language program that can:

1. Print your name
2. Read in 10 numbers. You must use a loop for this.
3. Print the sum of the positive numbers entered.
4. Print the sum of the negative numbers entered.
5. Print the 'program complete' and then stop using the correct syscall command.

My question is when I am asking for the numbers(#2) do I start the loop first or ask the user for a number using this code: `$v0, $0, 5`. Also for the loop, if I need to use labels do I store it under `.data`? If so how do I store them under `.data`?

```
.data
.asciiz "Victoria"
.globl main
.text

main:
    lui $a0, 0x1001
    addi $v0, $0, 4
    syscall
```

Comment: " do I start the loop first or ask the user for a number using this code: `$v0, $0, 5`". What do you mean? `$v0,$0,5` is not a code. Maybe you meant `add $v0, $0, 5` to write a 5 in $v0 for syscall 5 (read integer). "Also for the loop, if I need to use labels do I store it under .data" The best advice I can give you is to read your text books and lecture notes to understand what are labels. When you have understood it and written some code, come back here and people will help you to solve your problems.

Comment: For your code, it may work but is very dangerous as you have no guaranty that the string will remain at address 0X1001. Add `myname:` before `.asciiz "Victoria"` and replace your line with `lui` by `la $a0, myname`. This way whatever the address that the  assembler uses to store your string your code will work.  That is one of the important use of labels.